# 2-разовое изменение иконок JLabel после нажатия кнопки

Tags: java, многопоточность, swing

На фрейме 3 объекта JLabel. Первый и третий - с иконкой игральной кости, а вторая посередине - без иконки. После нажатия кнопки 1-ый и 3-й должны терять иконки, второй должен получить gif иконку - бросок костей. Через 2 секунды 2-ой должен потерять иконку, а 1-ый и 3-й должны получить в иконку рандомную кость. Моя проблема в том, что после нажатия спустья 2 секунды вижу новые значения костей, но не сам процесс, то есть, нажимаю, в течении 2-х секунд ничего не происходит, затем появляются рандомные кости. Я не вижу gif анимацию.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    int k1 = 1 + (int) (Math.random() * 6);
    int k2 = 1 + (int) (Math.random() * 6);

    label1.setIcon(null);
    label2.setIcon(new ImageIcon("roll.gif"));
    label3.setIcon(null);
    try {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
    }
    label1.setIcon(new ImageIcon(k1 + ".png"));
    label2.setIcon(null);
    label3.setIcon(new ImageIcon(k2 + ".png"));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в том что actionPerformed вызывается в потоке обработки сообщений и 
здесь же ты делаешь вызов Thread.sleep(2000); который вешает графический интерфейс. Метод Thread.sleep(2000); должен вызываться в другом потоке. Попробуй что-то типа:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    int k1 = 1 + (int) (Math.random() * 6);
    int k2 = 1 + (int) (Math.random() * 6);

    label1.setIcon(null);
    label2.setIcon(new ImageIcon("roll.gif"));
    label3.setIcon(null);
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {Thread.sleep(2000);} catch (InterruptedException e1) {}
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    label1.setIcon(new ImageIcon(k1 + ".png"));
                    label2.setIcon(null);
                    label3.setIcon(new ImageIcon(k2 + ".png"));
                }
            });
        }
    }).start();
}
```